# How do I find the area of the intersection of two circles?

Tags: calculus

I need help plotting the integral that finds me the area of the intersection of these two circles, defined by polar coordinates:
1- r=3sqrt(2)cos(theta)
2- r=3sin(theta)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Did you mean to write $1 - r = 3\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$ and $2 - r = 3\sin\theta$ or $r = 3\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$ and $r = 3\sin\theta$?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please edit your question to clarify what you meant, to show what you have attempted, and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.